# How to get friend's movie ratings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to build an app and my requirement is to get ratings given to all the movies of a user.

I was able to find this tutorial which describes how to get likes but not ratings. 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/18/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-pull-the-movies-friends-like/

Furthermore, I was able to find out this documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.rates/

But I am not sure if it can be done for user's friends and how to do it.

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try below path,

me/friends?fields=video.rates